# HHVM + symfony2 + capifony deployment error

Tags: symfony, hhvm, capifony

Did anyone came across issues when deploying with capifony hhvm stack?

I am getting errors just after vendors are done:

> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>   handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

https://gist.github.com/pawmart/15da1cc55d1ab5c4ba7c

This is Symfony 2.3.9

```
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
```

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/issues/154 ?